# R - Erro na função K de Ripley

Tags: r

Estou tentando fazer uma análise de distribuição espacial com o teste K de Ripley no software R. Tentei usar o pacote "splanc" e "spatstat". A minha dúvida é o seguinte, como faço para criar um polígono retangular com uma certa rotação (como na imagem abaixo). Sempre que faço dessa maneira volta um erro. Só consigo fazer evitar o erro se eu usar os limites superiores e inferiores de x e y, plotando um quadrado. Alguém tem uma solução?

```
require(dplyr)
require(spatstat)

s<-seq(0,6000,50) 

especie.pts<-as.points(invBind[,14:15])#  cria formato do splancs

poly<-(matrix(c(min(invBind$x),max(invBind$y), min(invBind$x), min(invBind$y), max(invBind$x),min(invBind$y), max(invBind$x),max(invBind$y)), 
              byrow=TRUE, 4,2)) 

envelope <- Kenv.csr(length(especie.pts[,1]), 
                     poly, nsim=1000, s)
especie.k<-khat(especie.pts,poly,s)

plot(s, sqrt((especie.k)/pi)-s, type="l", 
     xlab="Distance (m)", ylab="L estimated") 

lines(s, sqrt(envelope$lower/pi)-s, lty=2) 
lines(s, sqrt(envelope$upper/pi)-s, lty=2) 


> invBind
   Tree.no.      x       y[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1] Elevation Height Ht.to.crown.base Ave.radius...2 Ave.radius...2.1
1        17 798001 9710461         0  40.47            20.24           4.70             4.70
2        54 798127 9710622         0  39.10            19.55           5.60             5.60
3        72 798188 9710962         0  39.71            19.86           8.94             8.94
4       124 798371 9710834         0  38.73            19.36           5.26             5.26
5       328 799066 9711824         0  62.91            31.46           1.63             1.63
6       331 799074 9711780         0  38.75            19.38           2.94             2.94
7       349 799112 9711815         0  40.75            20.37           6.98             6.98
8       376 799172 9712011         0  38.34            19.17           6.37             6.37
9       379 799180 9712030         0  44.02            22.01           3.70             3.70
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de fazer um polígono tal como abaixo, com pontos definidos próximos aos pontos que já tenho, como por exemplo na imagem abaixo. Mas quando faço isso gera o erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
> envelope <- Kenv.csr(length(especie.pts[,1]), 
+                      poly, nsim=1000, s) 

Error in Kenv.csr(length(especie.pts[, 1]), poly, nsim = 1000, s) : 
  object 's' not found
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Tente fazer uma pergunta mais específica e use o `deput()` para podermos ter acesso a sua amostra de dados. Boa sorte e seja bem vindo.

Comment: Sou novo aqui , oque é esse deput()

Comment: No link que o Marcus Nunes te passou no primeiro comentário explica tudo.